# Robocopy to copy only new folders and files

Tags: command-line, robocopy

Objective: To find all new files and subfolders under some root folder (let us say Documents) and to copy them to another disk (`J:` in this case).

Command line used:

> robocopy  c:\users\valery\documents   j:\robocopy   /XO /E /MAXAGE:20131030 /XD

Result: A full folders tree is created. Only new files copied, which is the way it's supposed to work. Good so far.

A point is that I do not want to create all subfolders on a target disk if there are no new files in them.

Results are acceptable, but there is a lot of work to go through all folders and to find new files, as well as to understand what subfolders are a new ones.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add `/S` for that. You don't need the `\E` which is for copy empty directories. You won't even need the `\XO` which is done by the `\MAXAGE`.

> /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.

When no files are copied in a directory, the directory is not created on the destination.

```
robocopy c:\users\valery\documents j:\robocopy /S /MAXAGE:20131030 /XD {directories_to_exclude}
```

If you don't have directories to exclude you can just use:

```
robocopy c:\users\valery\documents j:\robocopy /S /MAXAGE:20131030
```

You can do a `robocopy /?` for all the help.

```
 /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
 /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
 /XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.
 /XO :: eXclude Older files.
 /MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, first of all! This is not a problem - not to copy empty sub-folders. I know aboout /s. What is /xd at this location in a command line? Maybe I did not point my problem correctly. When I use my command line the whole directory (folders) tree is created on a target disk. Then only "new" files will be copyed into appropriate folders. It means, that most of folders will be empty on the target disk. As I wrote, there is no so huge problem to enter folder after folder and to find where are "new" files, but is a fool work.

Comment: Sorry for a previous comment! I did not pay attention on /XD near /S. It works!!!!!!! I know about /S, but what does mean ?xd in this context? I feel its location in a command line is critical. I did not understand this parameter from robocopy documentation, sorry

Comment: You used the `/XD` so i assumed you would exclude some directories. BTW you don't need the `/E` which is for empty directories. You can replace that one with the `/S`. You won't even need `/XO` which is done by the `/MAXAGE`. I'll change it in my question. You add directories you want to exclude after `/XD`, if any otherwise you can delete the parameter.

Comment: I understood my fault. I did not realise that in /S ",but not empty ones" means also a case, when a source folder is not a "real empty folder" , but rather "a pseudo empty" - one, that does not contain files, created after defined date.  Thank you very much one more time! Valery

Comment: I think the documentation could be improved to describe the /s switch as "copy Subdirectories, but do not create empty ones" which would be much clearer for situations like this

Answer (score 7):

My simple commands that works wonderful is:

```
RoboCopy.exe  "\\\SourceServer\Folder" "X:\WEB" /copy:datso /mir /fft /r:0 /w:0 /secfix /mt:20 /xo /xf thumbs.db /log+:X:\TON-FS4.log /nc /ns /np /ndl /nfl /tee
```

Explanation:

- `X:\WEB` is my destination folder.
- Switches:

  - `/copy:datso`: Specifies the file properties to copy:

    - (d: Data, a: Attributes, t: Time stamps, s: NTFS access control list (ACL), o: Owner information)
  - `/mir`: Mirrors a directory tree
  - `/fft`: Assumes FAT file times, important when copying data
  - `/r:0`: Number of retries on failed
  - `/w:0`: Wait time between retries 0 seconds
  - `/secfix`: Fixes file security on all files, even skipped ones
  - `/mt:20`: Creates 20 threads copies
  - `/xo`: Excludes older files - if destination file exists and is the same date or newer than the source - don't bother to overwrite it.
  - `/xf thumbs.db`: Excludes "thumbs.db" files (path) you can use wild characters here (ei: *.mp3)
  - `/log+:filename.log`: Writes the status output to the specified log file
  - (appends to the existing log file) or to use a new log just /log:filename.log

Not this particular case but I hope that will help someone when they do file servers migration.

Comment: `/w:0` is redundant if you're already using `/r:0` as there are no retries for it to wait between. You can just use `/r:0` by itself and it will do exactly the same thing as `/r:0 /w:0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
robocopy.exe "Q:\TEST" "T:\TEST" /E /XO /LOG+:"T:test.log"
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
robocopy.exe "Q:\TEST" "T:\TEST" /E /XO /LOG+:"T:test.log
```

Just to break this down for bertieb - this code is meant to run straight from command line and not in a bat script.

**Set Source & Destinations:**

```
robocopy.exe "Q:\TEST" "T:\TEST"
```

`"Q:\TEST"` = Sets The Source Directory to Mapped Drive "Q"

`"T:\TEST"` = Sets The Destination Directory to Mapped Drive "T"

**OPTIONS USED:**

```
/E /XO /LOG+:"T:test.log"
```

1. `/E`   : Copy Subdirectories Including Empty Ones
2. `/XO`  : Exclude older files
3. `LOG+` : This will log the robocopy process in a .log file named test that will be in the root directory of the destination (i.e. Above the "TEST" folder on T). LOG+ will append the output status to the test.log file rather than over write it.

**SIDE NOTE:**

The `LOG+` option can be switched to the LOG option if you would like to only have the most recent session's information saved.

Easy to read version of [more information on Robocopy](https://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm) or the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).