# Avoid: there is not enough space on drive when overwriting

Tags: windows

I simply want to copy a folder to Network computer which already exists in the nextwork computer. This is to backup every month and I want to copy only the new files/folders skipping over existing files.

For the existing files I will simply choose to "Skip" copying. In that case only space for new files will be required.

When I try to copy -- Windows actually checks for disk space for all the files and folders to be copied. Actually space for only new files is required.

How to do it?

As in the photo, full folder size is 172G but the size of new files/folders in it is only 1G. So net space required is 1G only.

[image]

Comment: @Dave sorry for confusion, I've edited my question

Comment: Look up robocopy, it will help you automate this. I think this is a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/671244/robocopy-to-copy-only-new-folders-and-files but Robocopy also provides functionality to keep 2 folders in sync which may be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a simple copy and paste, you should do the stuff via a script.
It would be a lot more secure and easier for you I think.

Try using

```
robocopy source destination
```

this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Windows checks the disc size before the data. If this is for backup purposes, you only what to add data that has that is new. I would suggest using Genie Timeline (https://www.genie9.com/Home/Genie_Timeline_Home/overview.aspx)