# How to NOT overwrite existing files

Tags: powershell, copy

Currently, I'm using **Copy-Item** and wondering if there's a simple command that will only copy files that don't exist or are new files by date/time. Looked online but everything I see seems to be using **-WhatIf** command. Also, seen **-Recurse** being used. I don't fully understand what that command does either. Any ideas?

```
$From = "E:\Folder\*"
$To = "\\Server\Folder"
Copy-Item -Path $From -Destination $To -Verbose
```

Comment: if you don't use `-Force`, it won't copy files that are already present in the destination.

Comment: You are just doing a simple copy, and not checking for anything. Tunning this code will just copy files, it will not overwrite unless you use -Force, and since you are not checking for file properties, like timestamps, it's only going to look at names.

Comment: ***I am not really sure what the downvote is all about***, as what I said here is correct. But whatever. I explained what your post is doing in my comment. My answer is to help you help yourself. Otherwise, you are asking us to teach you online or write an answer for you. Your code is not broken, It is doing exactly what you asked it to do. You need to tell it more if you want it to do other stuff. Again, just use RoboCopy.exe. It is purposed built for this use case. [robocopy | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, what you are after is easily accomplished with `RoboCopy.exe`, and this question has been asked here and many other Q&A sites, multiple times. even here on SU.

> [Robocopy to copy only new folders and files](https://superuser.com/questions/671244/robocopy-to-copy-only-new-folders-and-files)

As well as on SO

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303532/use-robocopy-to-copy-only-changed-files

```
RC will only copy newer files. Files of the same age will be skipped.
C:\SourceFolder D:\DestinationFolder ABC.dll /XO

robocopy c:\users\valery\documents j:\robocopy /XO /E /MAXAGE:20131030 /XD
# Result: A full folders tree is created. Only new files copied.
```

So, your question is really a duplicate of the above.

Otherwise, you end up having to know and do stuff like the below(and if you are new, as you say, it's not easy to find in a single search or set of searches):

```
Clear-Host
$Source      = 'D:\Temp\Source'
$Destination = 'D:\Temp\Destination'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    If (Test-Path -Path "$Destination\$($PSItem.Name)")
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "`n$($PSItem.Name) already exists in $Destination. Checking timestamp`n"

        Try
        {
            "Copying file if $($PSItem.Name) is newer"
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Filter $PSItem.Name | 
            Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $PSItem.LastWriteTime -ErrorAction Stop
            Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination $Destination -Verbose -WhatIf

        }
        Catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "`n$PSItem.Name does not Exist in $Destination`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination $Destination -Verbose -WhatIf
    }
}
# Results
<#
...
WARNING: 
abc.txt already exists in D:\Temp\Destination. Checking timestamp
... 

WARNING: 
LexPointOh.txt already exists in D:\Temp\Destination. Checking timestamp
Copying file if $($PSItem.Name) is newer


-a----         10-Apr-21     00:00              0 LexPointOh.txt
What if: Performing the operation 
"Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Source\LexPointOh.txt 
Destination: D:\Temp\Destination\LexPointOh.txt".

mytest - Copy.txt.Name does not Exist in D:\Temp\Destination

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target 
"Item: D:\Temp\Source\mytest - Copy.txt 
Destination: D:\Temp\Destination\mytest - Copy.txt".
...
#>
```

***Just remove the `-WhatIf` for it to do stuff.***

So, based on your statement:

> ***I don't fully understand what that command does either.***

That being the case; then, what I show above would be more of a challenge. Hence why I pointed you to the help files (training site, Youtube, etc.) in my original post.

The above is just one way to do this. PowerShell provides various ways to do X or Y things. For example, here is another way of doing the same use case.

```
Clear-Host

$Source      = ($SourceFiles      = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\Source')[0].DirectoryName
$Destination = ($DestinationFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\Destination')[0].DirectoryName

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SourceFiles -DifferenceObject $DestinationFiles -IncludeEqual | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.SideIndicator -match '==|=>')
    {
        If (
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Filter $($PSItem.InputObject.Name) | 
            Where-Object LastWriteTime -LT  $PSItem.InputObject.LastWriteTime
        )       
        {
            Write-Warning -Message "`n$($PSItem.InputObject) already exists in $Destination. Checking timestamp`n"   
            Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.InputObject.FullName -Destination $Destination -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose -WhatIf
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "`n$($PSItem.InputObject ) does not Exist in $Destination`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.InputObject.FullName  -Destination $Destination -Verbose -WhatIf
    }
}
# Results
<#
WARNING: 
abc.txt already exists in D:\Temp\Destination. Checking timestamp

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Source\abc.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Destination\abc.txt".
WARNING: 
LexPointOh.txt already exists in D:\Temp\Destination. Checking timestamp

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Source\LexPointOh.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Destination\LexPointOh.txt".

mytest - Copy.txt does not Exist in D:\Temp\Destination

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Source\mytest - Copy.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Destination\mytest - Copy.txt".

...
#>
```

Yet, any time you are using comparative logic, you are not looking at simple command, in most cases.

So, use the right tool for the job. Unless this is a homework assignment, don't increase your core workload/Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't want to use Robocopy. I'm trying to get proficient in Powershell. No idea what duplicate this could be since all others just say robocopy.

Comment: @postanote thanks for the clarity. I understand that anything outside of the simplistic command requires more coding.

Comment: You might want to use `-le` rather than `-lt`, as a stop action, it should stop if less than or equals, i.e. only copy if newer,

Comment: In my case, I want to never overwrite any file by the same name, regardless of whether the source is newer, older, or a change. Basically I only want to copy over "Lonely" files. (Files in the source but not the destination.) 
When doing `robocopy /E /XN /XO /CX` it seemed to copy nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the cmdlet Get-ChildItem. Your script should basically have this flow:

1. Check if the file exists on the destination folder
2. If exists, then skip
3. If not exist, then copy

I ran a very crude and simple test on my computer and this should work (remember to modify it to your use-case)

```
$FROM = "T:\Files\Scripts1\BackItUp.ps1"
$TO = "T:\Files2"

if (Get-ChildItem -Path $TO "BackItUp.ps1") {
    Write-Host "file already exists..skipping"
} else {
    Copy-Item $FROM -Destination $TO
}
```

Comment: This is not enough as per the OP's ask, They asked two things.. `1. copy files that don't exist`  and `2. or are new files by date/time`. ***So, that is two logical conditions*** that must be validated before a copy should happen, which your answer does not provide. Again, `RoboCopy.exe` does all this for you by design. No Powershell required.

Comment: @balthazar Thanks, I wasn't sure if I made a mistake or not. Still new to Powershell and researching/testing all the time.

Comment: What about "*or are new files by date/time*".? Maybe `$_.LastWriteTime`, `Get-FileHash` comparison, etc.

Comment: @ITThugNinja I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Stack Overflow:

> ```
> Copy-Item (Join-Path $dir_from "*") $dir_to -Exclude (Get-ChildItem $dir_to)
> ```

Link: [*Why is `Copy-Item` overwriting destination files by default?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042909)